# Re-add ssh key every time I restart my mac

Tags: macos, ssh, git

Every time I try to interact with git after I restart my machine I and given an error saying I have been denied access.

To fix this I enter the command

```
sudo ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

This works until I restart my computer and have to enter it again. 
This is the [page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=302811860) that has helped me so far.

How can I get it so I don't have to enter this every time. 
Seems to work fine from other machines

Comment: I think you don't need `sudo` for doing that...

Comment: Without it says permission denied

Comment: Well, that's odd. You should _chown it_ (`sudo chown youruser:staff ~/.ssh/github_rsa` in order to regain permissions.

Comment: I have given that a go. I will let you know how it goes. Cant restart my machine right now.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone else still looking, I found a working solution on [Stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically), based on a question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/52zn5r/difficulties_with_sshagent_in_macos_sierra/) that mentions this problem, specifically with macOS Sierra.

In addition to `ssh-add -K` you also have to create a new file `~/.ssh/config` with this content:

```
Host *
   UseKeychain yes
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_25519
```

Worked for me, hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work for me on macOS Monterey (yes, old Mac here). Any ideas?